# ng-repeat: Limit to 10 most recent with exceptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got an unsorted array of objects:

```
[{ name: 'Daryl', interview: Sun May 19 2016 }, { name: 'John', interview: Monday May 30 2016 }, { name: 'Jim', interview: Monday May 30 2016, cancelled: true }]
```

I want to display a max of ten items, ordered by date, but giving preference to objects with a particular property (ie. any object with a 'cancelled' flag set to true will appear above the rest of the items). If I'm using an ng-repeat filter/limit:

```
<div ng-repeat="people in peoples | limitTo: 10 | orderBy: '-interview'">
```

how can I keep objects with the cancelled tag appear on top?

Comment: You will need to use a custom filter and do your own sort before returning array from that filter function.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-repeat="people in peoples | 
                limitTo: 10 | orderBy: '-interview' | filter:customFilter">
```

Your `custom filter` here below.

```
app.filter('customFilter', function() {
    return function( items ) {
      var filtered = [];
      angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        if(item.hasOwnProperty("cancelled") && item.cancelled === true)
            filtered.unshift(item);
        else
            filtered.push(item);
      });
      return filtered;
    };
});
```

Comment: For some reaon I never think of using `unshift()` and I would have had a horrible `sort()` instead... simple this way +1